# Get all column values from paginated jQuery DataTable with serverSide set to true

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables

I am trying to implement the `footerCallback` to find the sum of all elements in one of the columns of my paginated data table. When I try to calculate the total amount in all the pages, only the sum of rows in the current page is being calculated. My code for footerCallback is as follows:

```
"footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
                            var api = this.api(), data;

                            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
                            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                                        i : 0;
                            };

                            // Total over all pages
                            total = api
                            .column( 5 )
                            .data()
                            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                            }, 0 );

                            // Total over this page
                            pageTotal = api
                                .column( 5, { page: 'current'} )
                                .data()
                                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                                }, 0 );

                            // Update footer
                            jQuery( api.column( 5 ).footer() ).html(
                                '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' total)'
                            );
                        }
```

This function is given in the ajax call along with columns and columndefs. Both, pageTotal and total are returning the same value. When I try the `table.column( "#header5" ).data();` command in the console, even it is returning just the data in the current page.  In one of the websites, I read that, when server side is given true, `data()` and `fnGetData()` returns just the data in the current page. Is that true? If yes, how can I get the data in other pages?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's true. If you set the server side option to true, the datatables expect you to do the pagination processing on your server (i.e. the datatables request will ask for a given page of the data set, and your server must be ready to return the results of the query for the given page). If you are not dealing with great amounts of data and wish to avoid making the pagination yourself, you better set the serverside option to false and datatables will take care of it. This way all you need to do is provide all of the data at once.
More on it: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Thiago Franco. Is there any way to get all the values with server side set to true?

Comment: @rav The only way to do that would require the server to send all the data to the client at once, which kind of defeats the point of server-side processing. Probably the best way to do what you need is to write custom server-side code that gets whatever data you need from all rows and sends it, in its processed form, to the client (assuming you're opposed to just not using serverside)